# Webpage error details

Tags: html

Do you know why do I get this error in the browser?

*Webpage error details*

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Sun, 8 Nov 2009 10:54:36 UTC

Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 326
Char: 28
Code: 0
URI: http://www.netivot.biz/

Comment: Please elaborate further, how do you get the error? Is there a screenshot or Url you can provide?

Comment: @qaedus, please don't post multiple questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695837/ajax-loader-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, the clue to the problem is in the error message. If you look at line 326 of the page source you will see the following:

```
onmouseout="this.src='images/japes1.jpg"
```

There is an unmatched single quote in the JavaScript. This is the problem.

Comment: thanks !

would you know to tell me why it works fine in ie, bus got stuck in chrome and safari?